Extracting env variables in go
I am trying to create a dummy project in Go (I am new to this), and I am using a .env file to store my environment variables. This is my project structure:
Here's what my main.go code looks like:
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/caarlos0/env/v11"
)

type LocalConfig struct {
    Host       string `env:"DB_HOST"`
    DBPort     int    `env:"DB_PORT"`
    DBUser     string `env:"DB_USER"`
    DBPassword string `env:"DB_PASSWORD"`
    DBName     string `env:"DB_NAME"`
    Port       int    `env:"SERVER_PORT"`
}

func main() {
    var localconfig LocalConfig
    if err := env.Parse(&localconfig); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading the environment variables: %v", err)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("%+v\n", localconfig)
}

However, I am not able to see the values stored in the .env file just getting the default values
Screenshots of my project structure and .env file:
Project structure:

.env file content:


https://github.com/joho/godotenv

i tried using this too.. @DanielA.White
But I am getting exit status 1 and the lines and err. The system cannot find the file specified

@DanielA.White in load I provided the name of the file so godotenv is working, but since in my office project we are using caarlos0/env, thats why I want to learn to use it.

@DanielA.White ok.. I got it now, I added the lines given in godotenv first then I added the code that I was already using, now its loading perfectly. Thanks for giving a hint.

To make my Go application read environment variables from a .env file, I used the godotenv package. This package allows me to load environment variables from a .env file into the application's environment.
Here is how I modified my main function to incorporate godotenv and load my .env file (local.env):
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/caarlos0/env/v11"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

type LocalConfig struct {
    Host       string `env:"DB_HOST"`
    DBPort     int    `env:"DB_PORT"`
    DBUser     string `env:"DB_USER"`
    DBPassword string `env:"DB_PASSWORD"`
    DBName     string `env:"DB_NAME"`
    Port       int    `env:"SERVER_PORT"`
}

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load("local.env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file", err)
    }

    var localconfig LocalConfig
    if err := env.Parse(&localconfig); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading the environment variables: %v", err)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("%+v\n", localconfig)
}


Golang does not load values from your local env file to its environment automatically, you'll need to load them first to access these values.
